# Rails Form Image_Tag VS File_Field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post, controller

I'm making a profile picture the user can either get it from Linkedin or upload it's own. 
When the user get's it from LinkedIn it's shown via an `image_tag`:

```
image_tag(Base64::decode64(field_value), :alt => "profile_pic",:id => "profile_pic")
```

But the user can also upload an image:

```
file_field_tag("profile_pic")
```

These code is rendered from the apply_helper.rb:

```
def render_profile_image(field, alt, title)
 if field.nil?
  content_tag(:span, title) + tag(:br) + image_tag("user.png", :alt => alt) + tag(:br) +           \ file_field_tag("profile_pic") + tag(:br) + content_tag(:small, t("apply.create.labels.profile_pic")) + tag(:br)
 else
  field_value = field["VALUE"]
  content_tag(:span, title) + tag(:br) + image_tag(Base64::decode64(field_value), :alt => "profile_pic",:id => "profile_pic") + tag(:br) + \
    file_field_tag("profile_pic") + tag(:br) + content_tag(:small, t("apply.create.labels.profile_pic")) + tag(:br)
 end
end
```

I hope this is clear until this point, but when I do an apply and everything is filled in good.

In the apply controller:
`params["profile_pic"]` only shows content from the `file_field_tag` even when I remove it and only render the `image_tag` I can't seen to get the values into the `apply_controller`.

I thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the hidden_field_tag.

```
 hidden_field_tag('linkedin_pic',"example.url.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use same name for two different fields, they’re both going to be with same name in `params` array. So best to use separate name for both fields, for example `profile_pic` and `profile_pic_file_info`.

Comment: Dear, 

I have tried this only with an image_tag profile_pic https://www.evernote.com/shard/s314/sh/f9cfcec5-ccb1-4fc8-9014-9a0e286b275a/a61cb873607fae6c2125fc4819d2176c  

And in the create part of my control I set my debugger and I check the value of params["profile_pic"] and I recieve nil. 
The code that I used to render the image is the following:  image_tag("user.png", :alt => "profile_pic", :id => "profile_pic") More of my code can be found in this gist: https://gist.github.com/YOUConsulting/f2066fb330443b92fba6

Comment: Also tried, but did not work.

[CODE]     raw("<img id='profile_pic' name='profile_pic' src='/assets/user.png'/>")[/CODE]

or
 
[CODE] image_tag('user.png', :profile_pic =>'test') [/CODE]

or
:profile_pic = "test"

or
personal_info[profile_pic] = "test"

Comment: Rails automatically prefixes the ”param space”, so just ”profile_pic” won’t work. Best way to see correct key is to open a working field created with one form_for helper, my guess is ”users[profile_pic]”.

Comment: If you mean: image_tag('user.png',:id => "personal_info[profile_pic]", :name => "personal_info[profile_pic]") that does not work

Comment: something like that, yes. You can dump data with `env` and then you should inspect that those keys are correct in the form.

Comment: Is Rails Env Variables a "clean" solution?

Comment: Well, "Flash" isn't a clean solution because it's not compatible with people using flashblockers or on mobile.